# Aperture Master files

Tags: software, apple-aperture, iphoto

How do I create master files in Aperture so that I can email from within that application?

Most of a photos started in iPhoto originally.

Comment: Hi Colin.  I'm not completely sure what you're looking for, but Aperture has a nice "import from iPhoto" process which can move your iPhoto library into Aperture.  This seems like somewhat of a separate issue from the mechanism you use to email a picture -- it's pretty easy to email from either program.  If you want to use Aperture to organize & process your pictures, that makes perfect sense, but it's not clear to me this is necessary from your question.

Answer (score 1):

There is the ability to export directly to e-mail from Aperture.

Try this:
Choose File > Share > Email (or press Option-E).